# android relative layout and image background

Tags: android, image

Lets say I have a background image to a relative layout. That image is a circle, inside the circle I place a Text View with a single letter, how can I keep the text view inside the circle no matter what?
I made the image to keep the same resolution all the time, but still sometimes the letter is outside the circle.

P.S. Creating all the different layouts for high dpi, medium dpi, etc, wont work

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Majore C "
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="1090dp"
        android:layout_height="1920dp"
        android:background="@drawable/backright3" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/A"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/E"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/E"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/E"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
            android:text=" A "
            android:textColor="@color/Red"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: post your trying code

Comment: its kinda too big, many files, do you have any suggestions? on how to keep the textview in the circle when i switch to different screens and aspects

Comment: I've sugggestion, but i must be sure about what you exactly need. that's why i request to see your code. Just the xml file, try to remove extra views if it's too big and post it

Comment: ok i posted, something like that

Comment: Use `android:centerInParent="true"` property for the letter textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="1090dp"
    android:layout_height="1090dp"
    android:background="@drawable/backright3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="1090dp"
        android:layout_height="1090dp"
        android:text="A"
        android:id="@+id/A"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
        android:textColor="@color/Red"
        android:layout_margin="6dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update** (for many TextView s):

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="1090dp"
            android:layout_height="1090dp"
            android:background="@drawable/backright3">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="1090dp"
                android:layout_height="1090dp"
                android:layout_margin="6dp"
                android:gravity="center">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="A"
                    android:id="@+id/A"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
                    android:textColor="@color/Red"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="B"
                    android:id="@+id/B"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
                    android:textColor="@color/Red"/>

                //Other texts.......

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Z"
                    android:id="@+id/Z"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
                    android:textColor="@color/Red"/>
            </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

PS: The number of texts depends on *textSize* and the *Parent layout width*:

Comment: so if i dont have only 1 letter, and i have a hundred, i specify their width and height and they will be always in the same position in the image?

Comment: what do you mean about "so if i dont have only 1 letter, and i have a hundred"? same TextView with hundred letter or hundred TextView and each one have one letter?

Comment: 100 textview with each one have one letter, i place them in the image-background and want to be always there no matter what

Comment: i need the textviews to be in the relative layout, i think ill use your first suggestion with many textviews with fixed height and width, that should work, thanks